# What is the effect Cross-Multi-Labeling/Annotation on learning process?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, loss-function, prediction, multilabel-classification, yolo

I have a philosophical question regarding training convolution neuronal network. I am work on training NN for purpose of detection of Window and Window blind. This is an issue of cross labels; that is, in every window image there might be a window blind yet in every window blind image there must be a window. I managed to get dataset from Open image and now I am asking myself what is more effective for the learning process to show the network unique annotations in every txt file or cross (multi) annotations in every single image when available?
The same concept can be in the person-face issue. Should I tell the network im every image with a face that there is person and vice versa or only use unique annotations??

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:
Have a look at the YOLO object detection method of approaching this, it will help (even though you are doing classification)
Practically, just train a model to identify: windows, blinds, none - then fix the window-blind dependency in post processing. Validate your results by looking at the highest probability "blinds", to see if you have any without windows.

On the philosophy side, I believe a re-framing is, how much generalisation benefit is their on training a model to detect overlapping classes (shared knowledge). Personally I think marginal, at least not enough to start with that. Build your simple first model - then escalate from there.